# avoid postback on dropdownlist change in asp net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have nested gridview with dropdown list.when i change parent grid's dropdown box,Child gris'd dropdown box should change automatically. but after performing all operations due to postpack problem,child grid hides...

my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvParentMenu" Width="100%" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#000" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="menu_id"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanged="gvParentMenu_PageIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="gvParentMenu_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvParentMenu_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="gvParentMenu_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="gvParentMenu_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="gvParentMenu_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleted="gvParentMenu_RowDeleted" OnRowDeleting="gvParentMenu_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvParentMenu_RowEditing" OnRowUpdated="gvParentMenu_RowUpdated" OnRowUpdating="gvParentMenu_RowUpdating">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#76C4ED" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" BorderColor="#76C4ED" />
<Columns>

<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
<ItemTemplate>
<a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("menu_id") %>');">
<img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("menu_id") %>" border="0" src="common/img/button-plus-icon.png" />
</a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="menu_id" HeaderText="Menu Id" Visible="false" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="menu_desc" HeaderText="Menu Name" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rights">
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:DropDownList ID="drpRights"  runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("rights") %>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpRights_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="View" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="View & Insert" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="View & Insert & Edit" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="View & Insert & Edit & Delete" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="View & Insert & Edit & Delete & Report" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Report" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnParGridId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("menu_id")%>' />     
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-BorderColor="White" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="None" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="0px">
<ItemTemplate>
<tr >
<td colspan="100%">


<div id="div<%# Eval("menu_id") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 28px; overflow: auto" class="table-responsive">


<asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#000" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="None" Width="70%">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#76C4ED" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#76C4ED" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="menu_id" HeaderText="Menu Id" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="menu_desc" HeaderText="Menu Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rights">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpChildRights"  runat="server" Width="90%" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("rights") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="View" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="View & Insert" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="View & Insert & Edit" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="View & Insert & Edit & Delete" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="View & Insert & Edit & Delete & Report" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Report" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>

                </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnChildGridId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("menu_id")%>' /> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<%--    <br />--%>
</div>


</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C# Code here :

```
 protected void drpRights_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                try
                {
                    int index = ((sender as DropDownList).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex;
                    DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)gvParentMenu.Rows[index].FindControl("drpRights");
                    GridView gvChild = (GridView)gvParentMenu.Rows[index].FindControl("gvChildGrid");

                    gvChild.Visible = true;
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvChild.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                        {
                            DropDownList drpChild = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("drpChildRights");

                            if (drp.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
                            {
                                drpChild.SelectedItem.Value = "0";
                            }
                            else if (drp.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
                            {
                                drpChild.SelectedItem.Value = "1";
                            }
                            else if (drp.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
                            {
                                drpChild.SelectedItem.Value = "2";
                            }
                            else if (drp.SelectedItem.Value == "3")
                            {
                                drpChild.SelectedItem.Value = "3";
                            }
                            else if (drp.SelectedItem.Value == "4")
                            {
                                drpChild.SelectedItem.Value = "4";
                            }
                            else if (drp.SelectedItem.Value == "5")
                            {
                                drpChild.SelectedItem.Value = "5";
                            }
                            else if (drp.SelectedItem.Value == "6")
                            {
                                drpChild.SelectedItem.Value = "6";
                            }

                        }
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

        }
```

my screeshot:

Comment: if you using the binding code on the `page_load` then please use `if(!IsPostBack){//Here your full binding code}`.

Comment: but im not using the code on page_load. I have called child grid on parent grid's RowDataBound.

Comment: i think by default you are hiding  the child grid view. isn't it?

Comment: yes.. im hiding on my aspx page for nested grid. aspx page code here:.<div id="div<%# Eval("menu_id") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 28px; overflow: auto" class="table-responsive">

Comment: so actual problem is child grid is visible after selecting some value from parent grid's drop down?

Comment: but here child grid hides automatically when i select some vale.

Comment: is child grid is always hidden even before selecting value from drop down ? actually i think i got it. ill give you answer after this

Comment: no. i have a plus image button on each rows of  parent grid. when i click that image, child grid will open.

Comment: try the below approach. if it solves, but not what you wanted, then also let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! there it is

You are using a `div` for hiding the child grid. instead you can directly set the child grid visibility property.

So you can do like this

1. remove the `display:none` from child grid div

   `<div id="div<%# Eval("menu_id") %>" style=" position: relative; left: 28px; overflow: auto" class="table-responsive">`
2. Give directkly visibilty=false to child grid

   ```
   <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#000" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="None" Width="70%" Visible="false">
   ```

   ....
3. Now you can use

   `GridView gvChild =   (GridView)gvParentMenu.Rows[index].FindControl("gvChildGrid");
     gvChild.Visible = true;`

For making child grid visible from code.

(Please manage your JS for hiding for displaying div it not work,you can use simple JQuery for toggle the div)

Comment: I have changed my coding according to ur suggestions. Its working. thanx.